# Configure AWS EMR Cluster to read encrypted data from S3 but write unencrypted result to different S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Read encrypted files from S3BucketA using KMS keys
Write unencrypted files to S3BucketB

Answer (score 0):

If `S3BucketA` has default bucket encryption with KMS key and `S3BucketB` has default bucket encryption with no encryption or AWS-S3 key, there is no need to configure anything in EMR or application level. If the client doesn't specify S3 encryption headers, S3 will use the default bucket encryption. Only thing you need is the correct KMS permission in the EMR EC2 role (or whichever IAM entity your client is using) so that it can read from `S3BucketA`.